# Program only runs audio from desktop and not audio in a package on netbeans?

Tags: java, audio, netbeans

I've created the game frogger and want to add audio to it. The audio files are .wav.
If I use the file path for the audio stored on my desktop it works. But I want to use the audio i've added to package called "audio" in netbeans. But it comes up with an error.

```
private String audioFile = "/audio/retrolevel.wav";

  public void getSound() {
    try
{
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File(audioFile)));
    clip.start();
}
catch (LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException exc)
{
    exc.printStackTrace(System.out);
}

}
```

The error is

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \audio\retrolevel.wav (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioInputStream(WaveFloatFileReader.java:164)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(AudioSystem.java:1179)
at frogger.Board.getSound(Board.java:170)
```

If audioFile = "C:/Users/Michael/Desktop/Frogger Music/WAV/retrolevel.wav" it works fine.
I'm pretty sure the path is fine for the netbeans one so why does it not work with the file in netbeans?

Comment: If your file is located in Netbeans project folder try this way private String audioFile = "audio/retrolevel.wav"

Comment: Try to rename the folder "Frogger Music" I think the problem is the space but I am not sure.

Comment: The one using the file stored on my desktop works fine. So no need to rename the folder. Tried naming audioFile to what alexey said but no difference.

Comment: @MichaelHaywood okay never mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke a classloader in order to access files in your package. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) for API description. This is how it works:

```
InputStream inaudio = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/audio/retrolevel.wav");
Clip clip = null;
try {
    clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(inaudio));
} catch (IOException | LineUnavailableException | UnsupportedAudioFileException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
clip.start();
```

Comment: Completely forgot about that! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think your path is wrong. Do not use

```
private String audioFile = "/audio/retrolevel.wav";
```

Try to use

```
private String audioFile = "src/audio/retrolevel.wav";
```

Keep in mind that I have tried that with eclipse. In eclipse `src` is the default source folder. If it has a other name in netbeans, change it! Basically I added the above directory of the path to the string.